# Render background-image to canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have a DIV container with an image set as background-image (specified by url). Is there any way how to redraw this background-image into canvas (without re-contacting or re-downloading from server -- as the content image is once-to-show)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can get the URL of the background image, request the image file as `Blob`, create an `<img>` element, set `src` to `Blob URL` of response, at `load` event of created `img` element call `.drawImage()` with `img` as first parameter.

The background image could be cached, depending on browser settings. If the image is not cached at browser, you can request image first, then set both `css` `background-image` and `<canvas>` using single request.

You can use `fetch()` or `XMLHttpResponse()` to request `background-image` `url()`, `FileReader()`, `FileReader.prototype.readAsDataURL()` to set `src` of `<img>` to `.result` of `FileReader` at `load` event.

You can also use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a `Blob URL` from `response` `Blob`. `URL.revokeObjectURL()` to revoke the `Blob URL`.

Check `Network` tab at `DevTools` or `Developer Tools`, the image should be retrieved

```
(from cache)
```

```css
#bg {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image;
    img.width = canvas.width;
    img.height = canvas.height;
    img.onload = (e) => ctx.drawImage(e.target,0,0);
    var background = getComputedStyle(bg).getPropertyValue("background-image");
    var src = background.replace(/^url|["()]/g, "");
    var reader = new FileReader;
    reader.onload = (e) => img.src = e.target.result;
    fetch(src)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);   
      // const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);  img.src = url;
    })
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Will this method contact the server? Or do browsers handle it internally? The image i'm trying to get is generated per request

Comment: It depends on browser settings. Generally, browser does not send another request for cached image. If cache is disabled, you can use response from single request to set both background image and draw image to `canvas`. _"The image i'm trying to get is generated per request"_ How is image requested? Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried to solve issue at Question?

Comment: I'm displaying 3rd partys page which uses only background-images to dispay images (they never use IMG tag). My goal is to download all images (with the help of canvas), but i cannot afford to recontact the server as it will return another image (for the very same image URL; every displayed image has unique url, but recontacting server will yield a new image)

Comment: @LD Have you tried requesting image to determine if resource is retrieved from cache?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the image is retreived from cache successfully, thank you :-)

Comment: @Endless Yes, included mention of that option at updated post. OP does not have to consider `URL.revokeObjectURL()` using `data URI` approach.